# Show that $\mathrm{cl}\left( \varphi\left(\mathbb{A}^2\right)\right)$ is the zero set of the polynomial...

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $\varphi \colon (x,y)\in \mathbb{A^2} \mapsto (x,xy^2,x^2y) \in \mathbb{A^3}$.
Let $(U ,V ,W )$ denote the coordinates on $\mathbb{A^3}$.

Show that $\mathrm{cl}\left( \varphi\left(\mathbb{A}^2\right)\right)$ is the zero set of the polynomial $U^3V - W^2$.

I really had no idea where to begin.. 
Any hints are welcome!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you first show that $\textrm{cl}\left( \varphi(\mathbb{A}^2) \right) \subseteq Z(U^3 V - W^2)$?

Comment: Thanks for comment. But I don't know how to show this..

Comment: Are you sure about the map $\phi$ and about $f=U^3 V - W^2$? For $U=x$, $V= x y$ and $W = x^2 y$ you get $x^4 y - x^4 y^2$ for $f$ and not zero.  So $\phi(2,2)$ (for example) is not in $V(f)$.

Comment: I just recalculated: Probably $\phi(x,y) = (x,x y^2, x^2 y)$?

Comment: You're totally right! I apologize.

Comment: @JürgenBöhm Does your argument imply $(x,xy^2,x^2y) \subset Z(f)$?

Comment: How can I show that $Z(f) \subset \mathrm{cl}(\varphi\left( \mathbb{A}^2\right))$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$
$\newcommand{\spec}[1]{\mathrm{Spec}(#1)}$

Consider the commutative diagram

$$
\begin{CD}
k[x,y]_x @<<{f'}< k[\bar{U}, \bar{V}, \bar{W}]_{\bar{U}}\\
 @AAiA            @AA{i'}A\\
k[x,y] @<<f< k[U,V,W]/(U^3 V - W^2)
\end{CD}
$$

where $f$ is given by $U \mapsto x$, $V \mapsto x y^2$, $W \mapsto x^2 y$.
The map $i$ is obviously injective, and so is $i'$ as $(U^3 V - W^2)$ is irreducible and $U$ not a multiple of it.

The map $f'$ is an isomorphism, with inverse: $x \mapsto U$, $y \mapsto W/U^2$. See this explicitly:

$$
\begin{align}
U & \mapsto x \mapsto U \\
V & \mapsto x y^2 \mapsto W^2/U^3 = V \mod (U^3 V - W^2) \\ 
W & \mapsto x^2 y \mapsto U^2 W/U^2 = W
\end{align}
$$
The other direction is even easier.

So $f$ is injective and therefore $f^*:\spec{k[x,y]} \to \spec{k[U,V,W]/(U^3 V - W^2)}$ dominant, that is $\varphi(\mathbb{A}^2)$ dense in $Z(U^3 V - W^2) \subseteq \mathbb{A}^3$ in the notation of the original posting.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear proof! :)